# Mocking REST call to another rest-service

Tags: java, spring, web-services, rest, integration-testing

I've written a REST proxy that calls a REST service

```
@RequestMapping(value = { "session" }, method = {RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public String sesionGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse) {

            //call rest webservice    
            PostResponse postRequest = IncomeAccessUtils.postRequest(/*call web esrvice*/);
```

I need to do an integration test on that proxy but sometimes the server at which the external web service deployed on is down. Can I mock a response from webservice call ? I am using spring-test-mvc and/or rest-assure frameworks for testing.

Comment: Maybe http://wiremock.org/

Answer (score 1):

Yes there are several way of doing this in Java.

Without much details I would recommend looking at [betamax](http://betamax.software/) - it records any network integration and saves it for replay later. You can pass in whethere you want to run live or use the recording. (In one project we ran against real servers in the CI env but used version controlled recordings when running tests locally.)

SoapUI is another tool capable of mocking a web server. This may be a good choice if you work with WSDL and/or SOAP. (Poor you! :-) ) There are numerous such alternatives for rest out there but I don't have it fresh in my head.

A simplistic alternativ is to run pythons simple HTTP server: `python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8888`. It just serves whatever is in the directory where it was started. Put your reponses there as files and you are good to go. (Work with simple stuff but if headers etc is important not so good. Also not good at simulating failed calls.)

Finally if you are fine with not making the web call at all you can have mocks on the inside. If you use a dependency injection framework like Spring it is easy to run a version with mocked implementations of a backend call instead of the real one.